# Formal and actual Arguments

Tags: java

As I am going through the dumps for the preparation of OCA-Level 1 I encountered one question I don't know the answer to.

If a method is defined with three arguments, when you use this method with two arguments will the third argument be null by default?

a. YES

b. NO
 The code is

```
class overload{
    int ovlDemo (int a , int b, int c){
        System.out.println("hi"+ a+""+ b);
        return a+b;
    }
}
class EJava5{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        overload ab= new overload();
        ab.ovlDemo(4,6,9);
    }
}
```

For the above code it will have values 4, 6, 9
..................EDIT...................

But for this code given below has compilation error as the int c is not passed a value at ab.ovlDemo. SO i just need is confirmation that what will be third variable?
a.) Null
b.) 0

```
class overload{
    int ovlDemo (int a , int b, int c){
        System.out.println("hi"+ a+""+ b);
        return a+b;
    }
}
class EJava5{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        overload ab= new overload();
        ab.ovlDemo(4,6);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...What do *you* think and why?

Comment: You could write the code for this situation, run it, and see what happens.

Comment: I think third argument will be null.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: i write the code its giving the compilation error, but internally i m confused whether the third variable is null or not.If i want to check the third variable , how i can check..

Comment: What code? Can you update your question with it? Think -- why would the third variable -- and only the third variable -- have this behavior?

Comment: What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: can you pls tell me whether the third argument(whose value is not passed into method)will take null or not

Comment: Can `int` ever be `null`?

Comment: So does that give you an answer?

Comment: Well, now that you edited your question, this line of questioning is a bit moot... But a test program would easily give you the answer anyways.

Comment: means the third argument will be 0??

Comment: Well, technically you'd get a compiler error -- my initial questions were based off your question before you edited, and our edit changed the direction I should have gone. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 2):

> If a method is defined with three arguments, when you use this method with two arguments will the third argument be null by default?

As worded, the question is nonsensical, because you *can't* 'use this method with two arguments'. The compiler won't let you. The question of null-ness at runtime doesn't arise, because you can't get to run-time.

The answer is therefore 'no', but not for any of the reasons given.